# Show whether the sequence converges (sequence given as a sum)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is the problem:

Show whether $a_n$ converges:

$$ \frac1{2^2}+\frac2{3^2}+\dots+\frac n{(n+1)^2}$$

So what I tried to do is I tried to show that $a_{n+1}-a_n>0$ which can be simply proven given that $n>0$. What I am having trouble is proving if $a_n$ has an upper boundary. I tried fractional it to partial fractions and the best I can get is the sum of two separate sequences which I don't think does anything useful.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: Diverges.

Comment: You can do a comparison test with $\frac{1}{2n}$. This is what Jane's answer is. You could also do a limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n}$ which is what Bernard is doing. Either way works.

Answer (score 3):

This is immediate with (elementary) asymptotic analysis:
$$\frac n{(n+1)^2}\sim_\infty\frac n{n^2}=\frac1n,$$
and the harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Using that $k\geq \frac{k+1}{2}$ for all positive integers, one gets
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{(k+1)^2} \geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1}.
$$
The lower bound sequence obviously diverges, and so the initial sequence diverges as well!